# Reconciling pagination between front-end and back-end (for pull down to refresh action)

Tags: pagination, redux, react-redux, frontend

This post is more a discussion about a current problem I face with an app I'm building. I'd love to hear different people's opinions on how they'd implement this :) I'm using redux for the example but this question really extends to all front-end state management.

I'm building an app that is a paginated newsfeed-type list that loads the results 10 posts at a time. When I reach the bottom of that list then it will fetch another 10 posts and append to the list.

I'm managing my state as a hash of posts and a list of paginated ids. Every time I reach the end of the list I fetch the next set of results from my offset and push the new ids to the end of the list and this all works great.

```
{
    posts: {
        a: {
            content: 'some content'
            points: 100
        },
        b: {
            content: 'some other content'
            points: 98
        },
        c: { ... },
        d: { ... },
        e: { ... },
        .
        .
        .
    },
    popularPosts: [
        'a',
        'b',
        'd',
        'e'
        .
        .
        .
    ],
    newPosts: [...]
}
```

The problem is that I have functionality to pull down to refresh at the top of the list and fetch the latest top posts (like the way you can in the Twitter or 9gag apps).

The issue is that ordering by points is dynamic. So for example, at the time of the first request my posts ordered by points above is [a, b, d, e]. Now, what happens if people up-vote post 'b' a few points and now the order on the server is [b, a, d, e] when I refresh the next time. I could naively find a common sequence between the new order of the ids from the server and the existing order in the state and append the diff to the top of the list, but this a very basic example and you can see that for a high volume app the state will quickly become out of sync and introduce potential duplications.

It would be nice to cache as much as possible from the posts already loaded in the app and try to figure out where/how in the existing list of paginated ids I can reconcile. The easy solution is to wipe the state and start again, I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience of this and how they solved it?

Answer (score 0):

great question, for my part, at each refresh, i would use Array.sort and give it my compareFunction, so the element of my 10 posts will be sort as i wish.

Take a look at http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mean basically append to the array and sort the whole list again at after every request? It feels a bit wasteful to do this, if I have 10 pages loaded then I'm sorting 100+ results on the client side every time a new page comes in and performance will degrade as the list grows larger (unless I decide to truncate my results at a certain point).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of difficulty. So basically, you modify your state in 2 possible ways: 1. pagination and 2. pull to refresh.

Let's say you have 2 different actions for both of them: `FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS` for pagination and `FETCH_POST_REFRESH` for pull to refresh.

Whenever you fire `FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS` action, you should append the next 10 post IDs and when `FETCH_POST_REFRESH` action is fired, you flush the state array and append first 10 post ids which are there on the server itself. You don't need to keep the paginated ids when you refresh, you just need first 10 IDs only at the time of initialisation and anytime you refresh.

Comment: Yes so when you refresh you have to basically start all over again (similar to loading the page for the first time)? I think this is the easiest solution but the only thing is if a user has loaded 100 posts and say 5 new posts come and a user decide to refresh in then they have to go through another 10 page loads to get back to where they were (as opposed to scrolling really fast to the bottom). I think as a user experience this is pretty frustrating. Unless I've misinterpreted something in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to post my own solution and seek some constructive criticism on it :) For the purpose of making my solution easy to follow I'm going to use a page size of 4 posts instead of 10.

Let's say we have a list of 10 posts (so 3 page loads in this example)

```
 id | points |
 -------------
  a | 100
  b |  90
  c |  87
  d |  43
 -------------
  e |  30
  f |  12
  g |   5
  h |   4
 -------------
  i |   3
  j |   3
```

Now let's say I pull down to refresh and I get another 4 posts with the following results (some of which are already cached, but obviously with stale points)

```
  id | points |
  -------------
   g | 120
   z | 115
   h | 113
   e | 112
```

I know that my these results are sorted and I know that my cached results are sorted so all I need to do is pluck any common keys from my cached set (I can even query my `posts` hash from my question to build a list of search candidates without iterating for every item). When these ids are plucked then my cached entries should look like this.

```
 id | points |
 -------------
  a | 100
  b |  90
  c |  87
  d |  43
  f |  12
  i |   3
  j |   3
```

Now I know my *new* results set are higher in points than my cached set so I simply stack them on top to give me

```
 id | points |
 -------------
  g | 120
  z | 115
  h | 113
  e | 112
  a | 100
  b |  90
  c |  87
  d |  43
  f |  12
  i |   3
  j |   3
```

So the only issue I now have is determining if the new number of results that differ from the cached results are greater than the page size and under what criteria to I do another page fetch until I sync everything up. I could naively keep fetching until the sequence of my *new* results set matches a sequence in my cached results set

I know there's loads of edge cases here, just wanted to do a brain dump :)